# Visual Studio error C3861: 'pritnf': identifier not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I want to run simple "Hello World" example within MS Visual Stusion '15:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    printf("Hello world!\n");   return 0; }
```

I'm getting error when compiling it with MS Visual Studio '15.: 
error C3861: 'pritnf': identifier not found

I created app as console application (Template->Visual C++->Win32->Win32 COnsole Application) and as well as empty project (Template->Visual C++->General->Empty Project).

How to setup Visual Studio to compile pure C code?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it actually say `pritnf`? If so, you have a typo somewhere in your code.

Comment: Great - that was mistake - since i got several projects in one solution, typo is in another project. Thank you!